# Let x, m, n ∈ Z. Prove that if (m, n) = 1 and m | x and n | x, then mn | x.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x, m, n ∈ Z$. Prove that if $(m, n) = 1$ and $m | x$ and $n | x, $ then $mn | x$.

I'm lost on how to get it started. I know that

$m*a=x$ and $n*b=x$ but I'm not sure on how to continue from here or how to use $(m, n) = 1$ to help me

Comment: use $(m,n)=1$ to write $1 = ms+nt$ for some integers $s$ and $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ m,n\mid x\,\Rightarrow\, mn\mid mx,nx\,\Rightarrow\,mn\mid (mx,nx) = (m,n)x = x$

**Or** $\,\ m\mid n(x/n)\,\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{E\,L}}\Rightarrow\, m\mid x/n\,\Rightarrow\, mn\mid x\ $ by $\,\rm\color{#c00}{EL} = $ Euclid's Lemma and $\,(m,n)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

$nb=x$. Now, $m$ divides $x$, and so $m$ divides $nb$. As $(m,n)=1$, $m$ must divide $b$. Thus, $b=mk$, i.e. $x=mnk$, and hence...

Answer (score 1):

$ma+nb=1$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\to x = mxa+nxb$. Observe $mn | mxa$, and $mn|nxb$. So the result follows.

Note: It can be proved by prime factorization of $m, n$.